# css - how to make all flex items to have equal height and width but not using fixed value of height and weight

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have 3 flex items here, but the width of 2nd item is larger than others, since the description of 2nd item is very long.
[image]

Is it possible to make all flex items to have equal height and width but not using fixed value of height and weight, when the content of description changes.

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const containerStyles = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginRight: "10px",
    flex: 1
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        <div>Title 1</div>
        <div>Description 1</div>
        <div>Click to view detail</div>
      </div>
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        <div>Title 2</div>
        <div>Description 2 veryyyy longgggggggggggggggggggggg</div>
        <div>Click to view detail</div>
      </div>
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        <div>Title 3</div>
        <div>Description 3</div>
        <div>Click to view detail</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cookies-nw0ykj

Comment: for them to have the same width, use `flex: 1` on the children. for them to have the same height, use `align-items: stretch` on the parent.

Comment: @Layhout not working on my example

Comment: you need min-width:0 to the items

Answer (score 2):

The middle box is big because of a unbreakable word `longgggggg...`. If you overflow it to the next line, things are going to work fine for you.
Setting the `overflow-wrap` property to `anywhere` should work.

Try setting it for the flex container

```
  const containerStyles = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginRight: "10px",
    flex: 1,
    overflowWrap: 'anywhere',
  };
```

So you can see the text being cut in order to respect the width of the container so that you have equal width and height.

[image: After applying overflow]

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it.  This is better.

Answer (score 1):

Since I forgot you need the same width as well, I've modified my answer.

In your case, use both `justify-content: space-between` to made the child element height inside flexbox looks like equal, and `overflow-wrap: anywhere` to let the longer text to be wrapped to made flex items have same width.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your long word is what's breaking it.  You need to set overflow to anything other than visible.  You can also add in the word-wrap property to keep everything visible.

```
const containerStyles = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    marginRight: "10px",
    flex: 1,
    "word-wrap": "break-word",
    overflow: "hidden"
  };
```